changeset not working as intended when comparing folders
I have a Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    options {    
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }
    environment {
        TF_FOLDER = ''
    }
 
    stages{
        stage('Check for Changes') {
            steps {
                git(
                    url: 'https://github/org/repo.git',
                    credentialsId: 'repo-creds',
                    branch: "main"
                )
                script {
                    if (changeset("/dr/**")) {
                        TF_FOLDER = 'dr'
                        echo "Value of TF_FOLDER: ${TF_FOLDER}"
                    }
                    if (changeset("/nprod/**")) {
                        TF_FOLDER = 'nprod'
                        echo "Value of TF_FOLDER: ${TF_FOLDER}"
                    }
                    if (changeset("/prod/**")) {
                        TF_FOLDER = 'prod'
                        echo "Value of TF_FOLDER: ${TF_FOLDER}"
                        sh 'printenv'
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "No changes detected"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Use TF_FOLDER in later stages
    }
}

The root of my repo contains 3 folders
d-----         9/18/2024   4:33 PM                dr
d-----         9/18/2024   4:33 PM                nprod
d-----         9/18/2024   4:33 PM                prod

When the pipeline runs, I want to first figure out which folder has changes and then assign that folder's name to a variable called TF_FOLDER
When I made a change to any file under the prod folder
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   prod/test-prod

The result of the pipeline is
[Pipeline] echo
Value of TF_FOLDER: dr
[Pipeline] echo
Value of TF_FOLDER: nprod
[Pipeline] echo
Value of TF_FOLDER: prod

Is there something Ive missed in my code ? Im expecting the pipeline to assign TF_FOLDER = prod
EDIT ::
I changed the ifs to if else
and now the result is
[Pipeline] echo
Value of TF_FOLDER: dr
[Pipeline] }

Although the change I made is in the prod folder. Not the dr folder

Jenkins exposes changeset as a step, but it really isn't the same kind of step as sh or archiveArtifacts. It works as expected inside the when statement, but outside of it changeset returns a rather useless org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.UninstantiatedDescribableWithInterpolation object that doesn't cast to boolean the way you would expect.
You have two options:

Keep your current syntax, but move it to the when statement and add a bunch of stages, one per changeset
Access the list of changed files via currentBuild.changeSets. It's a lot more code

